# How to show multiple same date on timeline chart in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, timeline, angular2-highcharts

I'm using highchart and I need to show timeline chart but there are multiple same dates which I need to show on timeline but I'm not sure how to show multiple same dates.
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/timeline-series

Max I can show two same dates. Does any one faced this problem ? if yes, any idea hoq to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set individual positions for data labels which belong to points with the same `x` value. For example:

```
  series: [{
    data: [{
      x: Date.UTC(1969, 6, 20),
      name: 'First space station',
      label: 'A',
      description: 'A1'
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(1969, 6, 20),
      name: 'First space station',
      label: 'A',
      dataLabels: {
        y: 40
      },
      description: 'A2'
    }, ...]
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6vkm4za9/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.timeline.data.dataLabels

Comment: when adding more same date data, it is not coming up as expected, it is overlapping, 40 and -40 were fine then problem occured.

Comment: Hi @Anamika Singh, Ok, but would you describe how you would like to position data labels for overlapping points?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/anamika1593/4ayojnqc/8/ here I have added more data , for M not matter what y point I use it is stick to the B label and if I try to add more data you will see the commented data, on any y label, it will hide the M label  {
      x: Date.UTC(1969, 6, 20),
      name: 'L',
      label: 'L',
      dataLabels: {
        y: -40
      },
      description: 'k1'
    },  {
      x: Date.UTC(1969, 6, 20),
      name: 'M',
      label: 'M',
      dataLabels: {
        y: 200
      },
      description: 'M1'
    },

Comment: That's because there is not enough space for the data labels. You can increase chart.height to increase the available space. If some `dataLabel.y` value is too high, the label is just placed at the chart border. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/138fLkd2/

Answer (score 0):

if they have same date. but different label or title yes you can show them in chart. but if they are all same you can show the number of data on that date

Comment: How ?https://codepen.io/pen i have tried here but its not showing properly.